# MSVC (and icc) automatically calling memset C++

Tags: visual-c++, initialization, memset, overhead

I have intensively used big data structure and every time when I create (by placement new) it, compiler automatically added "memset" call. Even in Release mode, even if I set /SDL and /GS OFF. That is absolutely redundant and it produces some overhead that I don't required.
How to prevent redundant memset call generation?

[image]

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/wBVR6F)

Comment: I guess that with gcc at least you can use -ffreestanding and put your own memset in your code which does nothing. Or try initializing the struct variables individually..that might prevent the compiler from adding a memset.

Comment: If I add my own memset or do any other data initialization (even if I don't need them) - it doesn't help - MSVC generates that additional memset in any way

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `Tmp::Tmp()` constructor to get rid of the `memset`, i.e.:

```
struct Tmp
{
    String a0;
    String a1;
    String a2;

    Tmp() {}
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/J6-C8S